# What does CBI and nixio abbreviation for in LuCI?

Tags: openwrt, abbreviation, luci

I checked wikipedia: CBI = content-based instruction? And [official document](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/wiki/CBI), no explanation about CBI

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference link mentioned about CBI and also explain what it is. You can visit the website here : [https://blog.freifunk.net/tag/mvc-framework/][1]

I do not found the official explain about CBI, too. But I think the link I paste already explain it clearly.

hope it would be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

CBI is Configuration Bind Interface

Description:
Offers an interface for binding configuration values to certain
data types. Supports value and range validation and basic dependencies.

Source: https://gitlab.labs.nic.cz/turris/luci-cs/blob/a3bebe925cdefa56a1671d0919d797ef230cadd5/libs/cbi/luasrc/cbi.lua